# iPhone - Defining a MKMapRect with 2 MKMapPoint

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, geometry, mkmapview, point

How would you build the simpliest way a MKMapRect with 2 MKMapPoints, assuming that you don't know where are those points (the first can be lower or upper, more on the left or the right, compared to the second one).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way (`mp1` and `mp2` are `MKMapPoint` pairs of opposite corners):

```
MKMapRect mr = MKMapRectMake (fmin(mp1.x, mp2.x),
                              fmin(mp1.y, mp2.y),
                              fabs(mp1.x - mp2.x),
                              fabs(mp1.y - mp2.y));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also convert your points to 2 rectangles and get the union:

```
MKMapRect rect1 = MKMapRectMake(point1.x, point1.y, 0, 0);
MKMapRect rect2 = MKMapRectMake(point2.x, point2.y, 0, 0);

MKMapRect finalRect = MKMapRectUnion(rect1, rect2);
```